# Split Div content into two lines

Tags: css

I have a div as follows

`<div class="info">Some small information not more than 6 small words. <a href="#" title="Title1">title1</a> | <a href="#" title="title2">Title2</a> | <a href="#" title="title3">Title3</a> | <a href="" title="title4">Title4</a></div>`

I want the final output should be

Some small information not more than 6 small words.

Title1 | Title2 | Title3 | Title4

The text should be in first line and the hyperlink should be in second line. Any way to do it in CSS/CSS3 without **putting any extra tags** in between. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just asking. Why don't you use `<BR>`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd say the only way to do this would be to set a width to your info div.

Comment: you could use a </br> like Shiju said....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the commenters said, it would be best if you could alter the HTML code itself.
But if you can't, maybe something like this will help:

```
.info { white-space:pre; }
.info a:first-of-type:before { content: '\A'; }
```